# How can I apply a function to each value of a map to create a sorted sequence?

Tags: c++, stdstring, stdmap, stl-algorithm

Using STL in C++, how would I go about applying a function to each value in a `std::map` to get a `std::string` (printed representation of the value) and collect the `std::string`(s) into a collection that is sorted by a floating point key which comes from another function applied to each corresponding value in the map?

Stated another way, I want to iterate over the key value pairs in the map and create a new set of key value pairs where the new key and value are a function of the old value.

```
double getNewKey(origValue value);
std::string getNewValue(origValue value);
// Or is it better to map both at once in a pair?
std::pair<double, std::string> getNewPair(origValue value);

std::map<origKey, origValue> origMap;

// Perform some transformation on each value of origMap to get a new map:
std::map<double, std::string> transformedMap =
  /* What goes here to use getNewKey() and getNewValue() or use getNewPair()? */
  ;
```

But, please without using C++11.

Comment: Look into `std::transform` and `std::back_inserter`

Comment: though I think you need `std::inserter` if the output is also a map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::transform` is what you need:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

// using a few C++11 features to make life easier
int main(){
  std::map<int, int> src, dst; // example KV pair
  for(unsigned i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    src[i] = i;
  typedef std::map<int, int>::value_type kv_pair;
  std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()),
      [](kv_pair const& p){
        return kv_pair(p.first, p.second * 2);
      });
  for(auto& p : dst)
    std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/126ce2bb7fee6f4f75746b0d42887f7f)

Comment: How about without C++11 features?

Comment: @WilliamKF: You will need to change the lambda into a function/functor.

Comment: @WilliamKF: As David says, replace the lambda with a function/functor and obviously you can't use the ranged-for loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer, untested]:

```
std::pair<NewKey,NewValue> transform( std::pair<const OldKey,OldValue> const & x ) {
   return std::make_pair( getNewKey(x.first), getNewValue(x.second) );
}
...
std::transfom( m.begin(), m.end(),
               std::inserter( newmap, m.end() ),
               transform );
```